# Prove that $DD'$ also passes through $O$

Tags: geometry, triangles

Question - if $C$,$D$ divide $AB$ harmonically and $C'$, $D'$ divide $A'B'$ harmonically and lines $AA'$, $BB'$, $CC'$ meet at $O$ ..prove that $DD'$ also passes through $O$...

My try - I have spent a sufficient amount of time in this question but not getting anywhere. I draw two straight lines one above the other... but not getting how to use Menelaus or Ceva... Any hint will be very helpful.
Thanks

Source - CTPCM

Comment: This is your 8th question.  Perhaps it is time to learn mathjax.  Questions that show lack of attempt (using mathjax at least shows some attempt) is usually downvoted to oblivion and closed quickly.  See https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference.  For geometry questions, it is highly recommend to upload a diagram (some people consider this the minimal attempt for geometry questions).  You can draw it online using geogebra (https://www.geogebra.org/classic?lang=en).

Comment: @WE Tutorial School I think it seems very well without using LaTeX.

Answer (score 0):

This is a property of **harmonic pencils** of lines for which one can define an attached cross ratio. See :

http://alexanderrem.weebly.com/uploads/7/2/5/6/72566533/projectivegeometry.pdf

http://users.math.uoc.gr/~pamfilos/eGallery/problems/Harmonic_Bundle.html

Comment: I haven't learn yet these things...is there a proof using Euclidean geometry ?